# Eclipse showing error for a correct program in Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I created a simple spring MVC program in eclipse. I have added all the libraries correctly. The program runs correctly without any error. But eclipse highlights several errors such as
1) import cannot be resolved.
2) The class must implement the inherited methods even when it is already implemented. 
Here is the code

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.midhun.spring;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I did try cleaning and refreshing the code but that doesn't work. Even restarting eclipse doesn't help.

Comment: Try to delete metadata directory in the workspace, then start your eclipse and reimoprt your project (stop eclipse before delete the directory)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:-

Goto Project(Right click) -> maven ->Update Project

it will install all dependencies which are currently not found for ex-(import cannot be resolved).